# onchange not working with select dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: php, select, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 m0 col-xs-12">
                <div class="select-box">
                            <select class="select-menu" name="adults" onChange="getprice(this.value);">
                                <option value="default">Adults </option>  
                                <option value="1">1</option>    
                                <option value="2">2</option>    

                            </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The above is the html code of select dropdown. the onchange of that drodown calls a javascript function. but it does not calls the getprice function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getprice(val)
    {
alert("here");
}
</script>
```

The bootstrap automatically changes that dropdown into

```
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 m0 col-xs-12">

                   <div class="select-box">
                                <select class="select-menu" name="adults" id="adults" onchange="getprice(this.value);" style="display: none;">
                                    <option value="default">Adults</option>  
                                    <option value="1">1</option>    
                                    <option value="2">2</option></select>
<span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" id="adults-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="adults-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 71px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-4" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">Adults</span></span>
                        </div>

                      </div>
```

Comment: Use `function getprice(val)` instead `function getprice()`

Comment: Also check console error and share?

Comment: No error showing in console

Comment: Try to remove extra css link from your page or can you share whole page css links and J query

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 m0 col-xs-12">
    <div class="select-box">
        <select class="select-menu" name="childless6" id="childless6">
            <option value="default">Children < 6 </option>  
            <option value="1">1</option>    
            <option value="2">2</option>    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#childless6').on('change', function(e) {
        select_val = $(this).val();
        // rest of your code
    });
});
```